# random images from db, with links trough id

Tags: php, sql, random, limit

Having some issues, basically I have a random image gallery.

This is the code for the random thumbnails:

```
<?php
include('../../connect.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                       FROM picture AS r1
                       JOIN
                       (
                          SELECT ROUND(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id)
                                                 FROM picture) ) AS id
                       ) AS r2 
                       WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
                          AND public_approved=1
                       ORDER BY r1.id ASC 
                       LIMIT 4;")
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))  
{
echo "<div style='float:left; margin:2px;' >";
echo '<a href="pictures.php?id=' . $row['id'] .'"><img src="../../files/small/thumb0_'. $row['file_name'] . '.' . $row['file_extension'] . '" border="0"></br>';
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

When one of the thumbnails is clicked the page reloads and uses the following command to load the main content:

```
<?php
include('../../connect.php');

$passed_id = $_GET['id']; 

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM picture where id='$passed_id' ")
  or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 ))     
{?>
```

This continues on through a table displaying the larger image and title and so on.

I'm experiencing two problems:

1 - Even though I specify 4 in the limit, sometimes only 1 2 or 3 thumbs are displayed.

2 - Sometimes when I click on a thumbnail the wrong id is used, i.e. thumbnail id 2 but firing id 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose X is the number of images you want to display, you should really take [MAX(id) - X] as the RAND() multiplier. This way the result set will have enough results.

Second problem seems simple, someone will probably post a good answer, but keep in mind it's usually a column/parameter confusion in your php/html code.

Good luck!

Comment: Make sure the table always has more than X rows.

If it doesn't, make sure you use MAX(id) or just set the parameter X to zero.

Make it nice and readable, also make sure to write some documentation that lets everyone (including yourself a year from now) know why you did it.

Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are getting 1,2 or 3 thumbs is because r1.id >= r2.id where r1.public_aprove 1 only has a result set 1 or 2 or 3. The reason is your RAND().

For problem 2 which row[id] are you using r1.id or r2.id - I suspect its r2.id.

Comment: sorry but what does it matter whether is r1.id or r2.id both pull from the same table.